# Not enough input arguments Inheritance Matlab

Tags: matlab, class, oop, inheritance

I'm working on classes and their multiple inheritance, I have a problem which I couldn't solve after so many help, I have a class `A` which is base class and class `B`, which is its derive class. What I want is, the Constructor of class `A` with input arguments is to be calling in derived class `B`,supposed to be called in class `B` with its input arguments But unfortunately i have error Not enough input arguments. as Class `B` is expecting arguments but I want to give arguments as input in Class `B` like above.

*What solution is to be suggested or appropriate in my case?*

**My Code: (Base Class A)**

```
classdef A %base class
        properties 
            arg1
        end
        properties 
           out
        end
        methods 
        function  obj = A(arg1)
            obj.arg1=arg1;
            obj.out=[1 2 3;];
        end

end

end
```

**Derived Class B:**

```
classdef B < A %derived Class
        properties (Access=protected)
            arg2
            obj1
        end

        methods 
        function obj1 = B(arg2)
        obj1.arg2=arg2;
 A(obj1);
        end

        end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the [constructor of superclass](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/calling-superclass-methods-on-subclass-objects.html) `A` like this:

**B.m**:

```
classdef B < A %derived Class
    properties (Access=protected)
        arg2
    end
    
    methods
        function obj = B(arg1,arg2)
            obj = obj@A(arg1);
            obj.arg2 = arg2;
        end
    end
end
```

From [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/calling-superclass-methods-on-subclass-objects.html#bsa1tzj):

> By default, MATLAB calls the superclass constructor without arguments. If you want the superclass constructor called with specific arguments, explicitly call the superclass constructor from the subclass constructor. The call to the superclass constructor must come before any other references to the object.
>
> [image]

Don't forget to clear all instances of both classes before trying new code, and `clear A.m B.m` just for good measure.

**Usage**:

```
>> myA = A(1)
myA = 
  A with properties:

    arg1: 1
     out: [1 2 3]
>> myB = B(1,2)
myB = 
  B with properties:

    arg1: 1
     out: [1 2 3]
```

Comment: Hey, I understand this very well, but still confusion, I dont want to input `arg1` in Class `B` but wants `obj = obj@A(1);`. Is there any possibility of this, as my Goal is only multiple calls.

Comment: If you want to input `arg1`, then just do what you suggest with `obj = obj@A(1);`.  Just have a literal value in the call to the superclass constructor. Or for better readability, `arg1 = 1; obj = obj@A(arg1);`. If you can't take an input for the arg, then you need to hard code it as a default somehow.